# I get type mismatch error in for loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
'find the total of ages and anticor level to find the average

For i = 1 To lastCellNumber
    totalAge = totalAge + Cells(i, 4)
    totalAnticorLevel = totalAnticorLevel + Cells(i, 6)
Next i
```

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: Maybe one of the variable is string

Comment: One of the cells must contain something else than a number. Use `Val(Cells(...)` that will return the value in case of a number and 0 in case of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Using FunThomas's suggestion:

```
'find the total of ages and anticor level to find the average

For i = 1 To lastCellNumber
    if IsNumeric(Cells(i, 4).value) as sNumeric(totalAge) then
      totalAge = totalAge + Cells(i, 4)
    end if
   if IsNumeirc(totalAnticorLevel) and IsNumeric(Cells(i, 6).value) then
    totalAnticorLevel = totalAnticorLevel + Cells(i, 6)
    end if
Next i
```

But that would not calculate the cases where one of the parcels is not numeric, which would be your next problem to solve.

Answer (score -1):

When you do

```
totalAge + Cells(i, 4)
```

You're adding a value (`totalAge`) with a CELL (`Cells(i, 4)`).
You need to use the VALUE of the cell like:

```
totalAge + Cells(i, 4).value
```

Comment: Nope. `Value` is the *default*-property of a Range, both versions are equivalent. The problem likely comes from the fact that one of the cells is not numeric. Writing `Cells(i, 4).Value` doesn't convert anything into a number